# I want to add two different columns selected into one singular

Tags: sql

I want to add from two select queries in stored procedures into one...
what is written in the code is something similar to this:

```
select something from xxxx
select something from xxxx
```

and it produces two different columns
something that looks like this:

```
something
collecteddata1

something
collecteddata2
```

But what I want is to make it look like

```
something
collecteddata1
collecteddata2
```

If anyone knows how to do this please let me know!!!

Comment: I would look at the concept of a Pivot query.  You could also do the same thing with temp tables.

Comment: Do you mean columns or rows or resultsets when you say "it produces two different columns"? It looks like resultsets to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the following depending on whether or not you want to remove duplicates.

```
SELECT something from xxxx
UNION
SELECT something from xxxx
```

or

```
SELECT something from xxxx
UNION ALL
SELECT something from xxxx
```

Answer (score 2):

A guess, is it `union` you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

if there is relation b/w both the tables then query should look something like this

**Select table1.id, table1.data1, table2.data2 from table1 inner join table2 On table2.table1Id = table1.id**

If there is no mapping fields then

**select * from table1, table2**

Answer (score 0):

if your two tables have some relation between them on that field something, then you can do it using join

```
select x1.something, x1.data1, x2.data2
from x1 inner join x2
on x1.something = x2.something
```